# Jfrog-Pipelines - Kill multiple runs of a pipeline branch via REST

Tags: jfrog-pipelines

I want to kill hundreds of pipeline runs of specific pipeline and specific branch (without deleting either of them). Any idea how I can do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done via a script which first calls all the runs of pipeline with

```
GET /runs?pipelineIds=&statusCodes=
```

and then cancels them one by one using:

```
POST /runs/:runId/cancel
```

> Status codes of incomplete runs are 4000, 4001, 4005, 4015, 4016, 4022

Refer [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Pipelines+REST+API#PipelinesRESTAPI-GetStatusCodes) for more details